# checking whether current time is between time range

Tags: python

I am writing a python app where I only want processing to occur between a certain time range which is specified as parameters.

e.g. if the user provides parameters 9:00am 10:00pm, then the processing will only happen between that range.

The code below seems to achieve what I want however I am unsure how to handle the case where the start time is e.g. 11:00pm and end time is 08:00am. In this case 8am would refer to the next day however the code below wouldn't handle that.

Any advice?
Thanks

```
    now = datetime.now()
    now_time = now.time()

    if now_time >= args.start and now_time <= args.end:
        # Process as normal
    else:
        # Sleep until start time
        dt_now = timedelta(hours=now_time.hour, minutes = now_time.minute, seconds=now_time.second, microseconds=now_time.microsecond)
        dt_start = timedelta(hours=args.start.hour, minutes = args.start.minute, seconds=args.start.second, microseconds=args.start.microsecond)
        time_to_wait = abs((dt_start - dt_now).seconds)
        time.sleep(time_to_wait)
```

Comment: Find out whether the start time is greater than the end time and make a branch for each situation.  The first branch you already have.  The other branch will be something like this: `if now_time > start_time or now_time < end_time: …`.

Comment: You have the date information as well. Why not include the date as well as the time in your comparison? If arg.start is March 16, 2016 at 11:00 PM, then it's easy to say that March 17, 2016 at 1:00 AM is greater than that.

Comment: if `date` is not provided, how can you tell `11:00pm, 11:00pm`?

Comment: You must have date in order to know that 11:00pm today is earlier than 8:00am tomorrow. Including the date would make your current logic work for your second example

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone. I've included the date and it works good!